# How to install SVG-edit on Firefox?

Tags: software-installation, firefox-extensions

I download the master and run make.
https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit

Now how do I use this with Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Download https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit/archive/master.zip.
- Create a folder such as MySVGEdit in your home. Move `master.zip` there and extract it.
- You'll see a folder called `svgedit-master`.
- Within that, there's a sub-folder called `editor`.
- Open it.
- Within that, double-click on `svg-editor.html` and svg-edit will open in your default browser. If Firefox isn't your default browser, you can run something like `firefox path/to/svg-editor.html` and then bookmark the page for future use.

You can get quite a lot done with `svg-edit` but `Inkscape` is obviously more comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

> SVG-edit is a fast, web-based, JavaScript-driven SVG drawing editor that works in any modern browser

If you don't know what to do now, then you probably took a wrong approach. You have compiled a JavaScript SVG editor, that you need to embed in a web page...

If you're looking for a program to edit SVGs then you probably want to use `inkscape`.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it were worded something like this:  "If you are looking for an SVG editor,  inkscape may be more what you are looking for.  SVGedit is typically used for ..... "
Telling me I took a wrong approach and not saying what the right approach does not answer the wuestion and is inflammatory.

Comment: "worded" in what way?